# Jodit toolbar to be placed at bottom

Tags: jodit

**Option:** toolbar

**Expected behaviour:** Toolbar to have an option to be placed at the bottom.

**Actual behaviour:**   Currently there is no such option to place the toolbar at bottom.

It would be great to know if we have an option or if any style can be applied?